# Joining and nesting queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, I'm using this nice query:

```
select 
  users.name, 
  sum(race_results.winnings) as total_winnings, 
  count(CASE WHEN race_results.place=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS times_won_first_place 
from users 
inner join race_results 
where race_results.userid = users.id and race_results.place = 1 
group by users.id 
order by total_winnings desc
```

to get this

```
 ************************************************
| name  | total_winnings | times_won_first_place |
| Bob   | 4000           | 4                     |
| John  | 1000           | 1                     |
 ************************************************
```

the race_results table looks like this

```
*******************************************
| id | raceid | userid | place | winnings |
| 1  | 1      | 1      | 1     | 1000     |
| 2  | 1      | 2      | 5     | 50       |
| 3  | 1      | 3      | 6     | 50       |
| 4  | 2      | 1      | 1     | 1000     |
| 5  | 2      | 2      | 3     | 250      |
*******************************************
```

I would like to include four three more columns for something like this

```
 ***************************************************************************
| name  | total_winnings | total_races | 1st_place | 2nd_place | 3rd_place |
| Bob   | 4000           | 5           | 4         | 0         | 0         |
| John  | 1000           | 5           | 1         | 1         | 1         |
 ***************************************************************************
```

If I were to do separate queries for the new columns, I'd use

```
 select count(raceid) from race_results where userid = 1
 select count(raceid) from race_results where userid = 1 and place = 1
 select count(raceid) from race_results where userid = 1 and place = 2
 select count(raceid) from race_results where userid = 1 and place = 3
```

to do separate queries would be easy but with the existing query I had to use CASE just to get the count of times a user won 1st place. (using

```
count(CASE WHEN race_results.place=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

returns the same results).

How would I nest these or join them into my existing query to get what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
select 
    users.name, 
    sum(race_results.winnings) as total_winnings, 
    count(*) AS total_races,
    sum(race_results.place = 1) AS times_won_first_place ,
    sum(race_results.place = 2) AS times_won_second_place,
    sum(race_results.place = 3) AS times_won_third_place 
from users 
inner join race_results 
where race_results.userid = users.id 
group by users.id 
order by total_winnings desc;
```

With ANSI standard SQL you could use case expressions inside the `sum` function but since MySQL (and some other databases) evaluate boolean expressions to 1 for true you can replace the case expression with the just the condition to evaluate and then just sum them.

So instead of `CASE WHEN race_results.place=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` you can do `sum(race_results.place=1)` and save some space and typing :)

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2eaf9/1) for an example.

Comment: didn't saw your answer at first place

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid It's ok; happens all the time that people post the same thing simultaneously. :)